# IntelliJ IDEA & JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use IntelliJ IDEA's (13.1) resource sync feature with JBoss AS 7. I have set the 'On Frame Deactivation : Update Resources' setting under the Runtime Configuration. However, it seems that the resource updates (ex. JSP changes) are not reflected in the exploded application deployed on JBoss 7. I have to do a full redeploy to get the changes updated.

Looking into the IntelliJ's guide (http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_JBoss_AS) I see that they have mentioned for JBoss AS 7, a redeploy is needed.

Is there any workaround for this? Why is the resource update not working for AS 7?

Configuration: IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1 / JBoss AS 7.1.1-Final / Mac OS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is broken in JBoss 7.1.1: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4187 - you can upgrade to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad this is not there for the non-EAP release. By any chance, is this fixed on Wildfly?